# What does disliking a player do in DOTA 2?

Tags: dota-2

If I click "dislike player" after a match, what does that do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Dota 2 Summer 2023 Patch notes](https://www.dota2.com/summer2023) state:

> Additionally, we’ve added a “Dislike” button that will ensure players you’d prefer not to play with, for whatever reason, are less likely to show up in future matches.

So essentially, anyone you dislike you are less likely to get matched up with in the future.

Comment: This implies that matching up with them would still be possible if, for example, there aren't enough alternative options.

Comment: @Parrotmaster And the reason why it's a soft-criteria and not a hard "never matched again with that person" is because those systems tend to be abused by people to avoid getting matched with top ranked players. Those top ranked players would then end up in a situation where not enough people are accepting to match with them and thus, could not play anymore.